# Does CSS3 animation create memory leaks?

Tags: css, animation, memory, memory-leaks

http://jsfiddle.net/q5yncg61/

```css
.vertical-line {
/* will-change: transform; */
 stroke-dasharray: 2;
 -webkit-animation: dash 25s infinite linear;
 animation: dash 18s infinite linear;
 stroke-width: 2px;
}
.firstCircle {
  fill: #333333;
  stroke-width: 3px;
  stroke-color: #979797;
  transform: scale(1);
  transform-origin: center center;
  animation: pulse 5s linear infinite;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.secondCircle {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 100;
  }
}
@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.75);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 179" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g class="draw" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-linecap="square">
      <line x1="50%" y1="0%" x2="50%" y2="100%" id="vertical-line" stroke="#979797" stroke-width="0.5"></line>

  <circle class="firstCircle" stroke="#555555" stroke-width="5" r="25" cx="50" cy="50" fill="#777777"></circle>
  <circle class="secondCircle" stroke="#999999" r="25" cx="50" cy="50" fill="#999999"></circle>

    </g>
</svg>
```

On my local, it's running a lightly more complex version of the jsfiddle example but same elements repeated 5 times, not in a loop. On Safari I kept getting a memory issue after the fan was running at warp speed. Is this an issue with rendering from GPU instead of CPU? Is this a memory leak issue?

If not, are there any ideas what may be causing the issue? I've verified it is the svg causing the slow performance as I've removed it and the page was loading fine. Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

sure, the 'transition' of CSS cause a obviously Memory Leak on Chrome at least.